# D3 / C3 - animate data selection and hover?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, c3.js

The built in animations that come with C3js are great, and I would like to schedule the 'series selection' from the legend.

Is is possible to have the graph load with no series selected, and then load each series in sequence?

The animation I am after is:
1. graph loads blank
2. series 1 is selected (e.g. "Order Lines Processed")
3. series 2 is selected

I have tried loading data incrementally with the C3 'transition' approach, but the animations have less, shall we say, management appeal.

```
transition: {
    duration: 1500
},
```

Any advice appreciated!

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fd7k0x31/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

C3js has the following chart level functions available:

```
// toggle enabled or disabled    
chart.toggle('chart series name');
// set focus
chart.focus('chart series name');
// reset chart
chart.revert();
```

[JSFiddle updated to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/fd7k0x31/5/) (need to hit run to see it do it's thing)